# What kind of join to I need here in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Please help me first to make a clearer subject for that question.
To point is I don't know the correct R-terminology for what I need here. Is "join" a correct word?

```
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(a = sample(c(T,F), 10, replace=TRUE),
                 b = sample(c(T,F), 10, replace=TRUE),
                 c = sample(c(T,F), 10, replace=TRUE),
                 d = sample(c(T,F), 10, replace=TRUE))

a <- addmargins(table(df$a))
b <- addmargins(table(df$b))
c <- addmargins(table(df$c))
d <- addmargins(table(df$d))
```

This is the data

```
FALSE  TRUE   Sum 
    7     3    10 

FALSE  TRUE   Sum 
    4     6    10 

FALSE  TRUE   Sum 
    4     6    10 

FALSE  TRUE   Sum 
    5     5    10
```

And what I want is to make the data look like this

```
   FALSE  TRUE   Sum 
a      7     3    10 
b      4     6    10 
c      4     6    10 
d      5     5    10
```

Sounds simple, dosn't it? I was using `ddply` in the past. But I don't get here how to use `ddply` or anything else.

Comment: Something like this: `addmargins(t(sapply(df, table)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple one-liner to perform the table command and then to add the margins:

```
addmargins(t(sapply(df, table)))

#or this for just the row sums:
addmargins(t(sapply(df, table)), 2)
```

`sapply` to apply the `table` function to each column.
`t` to transpose the results
`addmargins` for the row/column sums

Answer (score 3):

This is just stacking rows, you want `rbind` (for "binding" rows together. `cbind` is the equivalent for columns).

```
rbind(a, b, c, d)
#   FALSE TRUE Sum
# a     7    3  10
# b     4    6  10
# c     4    6  10
# d     5    5  10
```

A *join* is typically done when you have some shared columns but some different columns, and you want to combine the data such that the shared columns line up, and the different corresponding different columns are kept. For example, if you had one data frame of people and addresses, and another data frame of people and orders, you would join them together to see which address goes with which order. In base R, joins are done with the `merge` command.